# Combinatorial Optimization - Fewest Columns in Matrix

Tags: optimization, combinations

I'm trying to resolve, obtain a algorithm, for the problem that follows:

Having a matrix with n columns and each column is the same length, what's the minimum number of columns so I can get all values of the matrix.

Ex: Matrix with 4 columns and 3 rows with values from 1 to 9

```
A  B  C  D

1  4  4  5
2  5  7  6
3  6  8  9
```

Looking at the matrix the optimal number of columns would be A, C, and D.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: This seems likely to be equivalent to the set cover problem, which would make it extremely difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems to be equivalent to the [set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

Comment: Thanx Sebastian, indeed it seems to be the same. Do you know where i could find some pseudo-code with the implementation of the algorithm.